# Display Total Sum of a Dynamic Input

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dynamic, user-input

I am trying to calculate the sum of a dynamic div for different categories, and then place that value in a div. What I don't understand, is how to figure out the total based on different categories. Here is a screencast of what I am talking about https://www.screencast.com/t/js8LBNfXo9sa. Here is also a link to my code pen which houses my code https://codepen.io/nfinsand/project/full/ZLNEon/.

```js
var addListItem = document.getElementById("add-more");

addListItem.addEventListener("click", function() {
  createNewItem();
});

//Display Month and Day
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth() + 1;

today = mm + "/" + dd;
document.getElementById("current-date").innerHTML = today;

//Creates new elements
function createNewItem() {
  var u = document.getElementById("full-item-list");
  var l = document.createElement("li");
  var elinput = document.createElement('input');
  var expenseName = document.createElement('input');
  var icon = document.createElement('img');
  var optionsArray = [{
      'itemText': 'Category',
      'itemDisabled': true,
      'itemSelected': true
    },
    'Auto & Transport',
    'Health & Fitness',
    'Home',
    'Personal Care',
    'Pets',
    'Shopping',
    'Entertainment',
    'Investments'
  ];

  var selectElem = document.createElement('select');
  selectElem.setAttribute('name', 'selectThis');
  // iterate through the array of options
  optionsArray.forEach(function(item) {
    var text = (typeof(item) === 'string') ? item : item.itemText;
    var option = document.createElement('option');
    var optionText = document.createTextNode(text);
    option.appendChild(optionText);
    if (typeof(item) === 'object') {
      // handle custom attributes
      Object.keys(item).forEach(function(key) {
        switch (key) {
          case 'itemDisabled':
            if (item[key]) {
              option.setAttribute('disabled', true);
            }
            break;
          case 'itemSelected':
            if (item[key]) {
              option.setAttribute('selected', true);
            }
            break;
          default:
            break;
        }
      });
    }
    selectElem.appendChild(option);
  });

  expenseName.setAttribute('type', 'text');
  expenseName.setAttribute('placeholder', 'Expense name');
  expenseName.setAttribute('class', 'expense-input-name')
  expenseName.setAttribute('name', 'totalExpense');

  elinput.setAttribute('type', 'number');
  elinput.setAttribute('class', 'li-input');
  elinput.setAttribute('placeholder', 'Enter amount');
  elinput.setAttribute('name', 'qty');

  l.setAttribute('class', 'list-item');
  l.setAttribute('name', 'li-name');
  icon.setAttribute('class', 'remove-icon');
  icon.setAttribute('src', 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/375261/System_Delete.ico');
  icon.setAttribute("id", "icon-id");
  icon.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    thaticon(e);
  }, false);
  l.appendChild(selectElem);
  l.appendChild(expenseName);
  l.appendChild(elinput);
  l.appendChild(icon);
  u.appendChild(l);
}

//Deletes elements
function thaticon(e) {
  console.log("test");
  var el = e.target;
  var elListItem = el.parentNode;
  elFullList = elListItem.parentNode;
  elFullList.removeChild(elListItem);
}

//Calculates and displays results
function displayResult() {
  var arr = document.getElementsByName("qty");
  var wage = document.getElementById("inputWage").value;
  var jumboDiv = document.getElementById("jumbo-results").style.display = "block";
  var tot = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (parseFloat(arr[i].value)) tot += parseFloat(arr[i].value);
  }
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Total Expenses: $" + tot.toFixed(2);
  document.getElementById("left").innerHTML = "Left Over: $" + ((wage - tot).toFixed(2));
}

//Resets and clears entire entry
function resetForm() {
  var jumboDiv = document.getElementById("jumbo-results").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("full-item-list").innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById("inputWage").value = "";
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById("left").innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById("number-display").innerHTML = "";
}

//Displays the selected categories by user with the total sum for each one
function displayCategory() {

}
//Capture screen shots
/*function captureScreen() {
  html2canvas(document.querySelector("#capture")).then(canvas => {
      document.body.appendChild(canvas)
  });
}*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Expense Tracker</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.css'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="capture" class="container-fluid">
    <div class="centerDiv">
      <p class="mainHeading">Expense Calculator</p>
      <p id="current-date"></p>
      <div class="jumbotron jumbo2">
        <h4>Categories</h4>
        <div id="category-display"><br>
          <div class="flex-container">
            <div id="color-1"></div>
            <div class="categoryItem">Auto & Transport</div>
            <div class="well">$0.00</div>
          </div>
          <div class="flex-container">
            <div id="color-2"></div>
            <div class="categoryItem">Health & Fitness</div>
            <div class="well">$0.00</div>
          </div>
          <div class="flex-container">
            <div id="color-3"></div>
            <div class="categoryItem">Home</div>
            <div class="well">$0.00</div>
          </div>
          <div class="flex-container">
            <div id="color-4"></div>
            <div class="categoryItem">Personal Care</div>
            <div class="well">$0.00</div>
          </div>
          <div class="flex-container">
            <div id="color-5"></div>
            <div class="categoryItem">Pets</div>
            <div class="well">$0.00</div>
          </div>
          <div class="flex-container">
            <div id="color-6"></div>
            <div class="categoryItem">Shopping</div>
            <div class="well">$0.00</div>
          </div>
          <div class="flex-container">
            <div id="color-7"></div>
            <div class="categoryItem">Entertainment</div>
            <div class="well">$0.00</div>
          </div>
          <div class="flex-container">
            <div id="color-8"></div>
            <div class="categoryItem">Investments</div>
            <div class="well">$0.00</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="jumbotron">
        <label class="expenseLabel">Income:</label><br>
        <input id="inputWage" type="number" placeholder="Paycheck Amount"><br><br><br>
        <label>Expenses:</label>
        <ul id="full-item-list"></ul>
        <div class="listItem">
          <button id="add-more" class='btn btn-warning addExpenseBtn'>Add Expense</button>
          <button class="btn btn-warning submitExpenseBtn" type="button" onclick="displayResult(); displayCategory()">Submit</button>
          <button class="btn btn-warning resetExpenseBtn" type="button" onclick="resetForm()">Reset</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="jumbo-results" class="jumbotron">
        <p id="result"></p><br>
        <p id="left"></p>
      </div>
      <button class="btn btn-warning captureBtn" onclick="captureScreen()">Save Me</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <footer>
    <small>&copy; Copyright 2018, Noble Finsand</small>
  </footer>
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
  <script src="js/index.js"></script>
  <script src="js/html2canvas.js"></script>
  <script src="js/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: With a bit of jQuery your code would look much cleaner - is this an option or you want to stick to *pure* Javascript?

Comment: jQuery is an option!

Answer (score 0):

In order to calculate the total based on the categories, you will need to create a list of objects that have all the data the user entered.

From a code hygiene perspective creating the list and performing calculations on it should be separate tasks.

Similar to how you are looping through all the `qty` fields entered by the user in `displayResult` you can build out your list of expenses and then process that final result. Handling validation of each part will be challenging as they are all different fields and not guaranteed to have valid data.

Something like Angular can make this a lot easier as the hard part of binding input fields to a model is taken care of for you.

Regardless of how you create the list calculating the total by category is simple.

Assuming you create a list like this

```
var myExpenses = [
    {'category': 'Home', name: 'rent', 'amount': 500},
    {'category': 'Pets', name: 'cat food', 'amount': 45},
    {'category': 'Home', name: 'utilities', 'amount': 200},
    {'category': 'Pets', name: 'vet', 'amount': 42},
    {'category': 'Home', name: 'trash', 'amount': 50},
    {'category': 'Entertainment', name: 'date night', 'amount': 80}
];
```

Then these functions will be able to return you the grand total of all the expenses and each expense based on your categories.

```
function totalExpenses (expenses) {
    return expenses.reduce(function (total, expense) {
        return total + expense.amount;
    }, 0);
}

function totalExpenseByCategory(categories, expenses) {
    var categorizedExpenses = [];
    categories.map(function (category) {
        var currentExpenses = expenses.filter(function (expense) {
            return expense.category === category;
        });
        var total = totalExpenses(currentExpenses);
        categorizedExpenses.push({'category': category, 'amount': total})
    });
    return categorizedExpenses;
}
```

These functions use Filter, Map and Reduce on arrays to calculate the totals. You can learn more about them here.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce